# How can Grafana be configured to catch a steep drop in a metric from Prometheus?

Tags: prometheus, grafana

We're using Grafana to monitor certain events and fire alarms. The data is stored in Prometheus (but we're not using the Prometheus Alert Manager).

Last night we had an issue with one of our metrics that we currently do not have an alarm on. I would like to add one, but I'm struggling to determine the best way to do so.

[image: Image of Grafana dashboard with sine wave pattern - except for sharp drop]

In this case, the Y axis for this metric is pretty low, and overnight (02:00-07:00 on the left of the graph) you can see the metric drops near to zero.

We'd like to detect the sharp drop on the right hand side at 8pm. We detected the drop to completely zero at ~9pm (the flatline), but I'd like to identify the sudden drop.

Our prometheus query is:

```
sum(rate({__name__=~"metric_name_.+"}[1m])) by (grouping)
```

I've tried looking at a few things like:

```
sum(increase({__name__=~"metric_name_.+"}[1m])) by (grouping)
```

But they broadly all end up with a similar looking graph to the one below, but with a variance on the Y-axis scale and make it tricky to differentiate between "near zero & quiet" and "near zero because the metrics have dropped off a cliff".

What combination of Grafana and Prometheus settings can we use to identify this change effectively?

Answer (score 4):

You have got the wrong function: for gauge, you should use the [delta() function](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#delta). It will expose the drop over a minute:

```
sum(delta(rate({__name__=~"metric_name_.+"}[1m])[1m:])) by (grouping)
```

The next step is to define a percentage of drop that will trigger the error - with a 80% drop (note: omitting the `sum by(grouping)` for clarity):

```
(-100 * delta(rate({__name__=~"metric_name_.+"}[1m])[1m:]) / rate({__name__=~"metric_name_.+"}[1m] offset 1m)) > 80
```

Then, you may want to have a duration of alert once a drop has been detected. In this case, you have to use subqueries or a recording rule (named here `drop_rate_percent`):

```
rules:
- record: metric_name_rate
  expr: sum(rate({__name__=~"metric_name_.+"}[1m])) by(grouping)

- record: drop_rate_percent
  expr: -100 * delta(metric_name_rate[1m]) / (metric_name_rate offset 1m)

- alert: SteepDrop
  expr: max_over_time(drop_rate_percent[15m]) > 80
```

Comment: Thanks @michael-doubez. I'm not sure I'm getting this right, my apologies. If I filter down to to a single host to avoid the sum problem, I end up with a graph like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYhqV.png. It's the same shape as the `rate` function, but with a vastly smaller axis. Swapping to a gauge just shows a value with `0.00031`.  Could you elaborate on your query a little more - e.g. why 100? And why dividing the delta by the total? Also, `> 80%` causes an error too ("parse error at char 189: no valid expression found", I'm on prometheus 1.6.3 if that's relevant). Thanks for your help!

Comment: Here's my full query to provide a bit of additional context from the image:

`100 * (delta({__name__=~"[[env]]_pubsub_mm_events_live_ref.+",host="ip-172-20-4-73"}[1m]) / {__name__=~"[[env]]_pubsub_mm_events_live_ref.+",host="ip-172-20-4-73"} offset 1m)`

Comment: Yes, sorry. It should be 80 not 80% - I got carried away in the logic.

Comment: The logic is to compute the percentage of drop over one minute (or longer). `delta(foo[1m])` give you the difference of value in range and `foo offset 1m` gives you the value at the beginning of the delta. The ratio of those values multiplied by -100 gives you the information of drop scale.

Comment: Noté that I chose 1m randomly. Depending on the shape of your data you may want to take a larger value.

Comment: Thanks @michael-doubez. Charting our numerator and denominator I get values of ~0 to 700 divided by currently ~16 million. Like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mwrGw.png

Which leads to a calculation like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GYSBq.png, where the number on the left axis is very small - the value for drop scale doesn't seem like it should be 0.0003 when it collapses to 0? 

Also, adding > 80 shows no data, like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JOcf5.png.

Comment: Am I right in saying what we're calculating here therefore is the rate of change of the overall number (which is why I'm getting very small values - because the total is currently very large, and the changes are very small) - so I'm seeing a rate of 0.0003% change on the 16 million number? Whereas, what I'm after I think is the rate of change _of_ the rate of change. I.e. the rate has dropped from 0.0003% to 0% which is a change of 100%. Does that make sense? Is that possible/sensible? Cheers

Comment: Yes. If the "steep drop" I took to be the actual metric is another expression (like a rate) then you should apply the elements of my answer to you expression. Note that it then requires subqueries which may be expensive. A recording rule may save you cycles and typing.

Comment: Ah - yes. Sorry, my original graph is a rate. What you've got now makes sense - but I can't seem to get the query to work. `delta(rate({__name__=~"metric_name_.+"}[1m])[1m:])` gives: ` range specification must be preceded by a metric selector, but follows a *promql.Call instead`. If I take the range out, I get ` expected type range vector in call to function "delta", got instant vector"`. I can't seem to find anything about combining rate and delta. Is this a version problem? Or another flaw? Thanks again for all your help here @michael-doubez.

Comment: Yes, you need subquery support which were added in Prometheus 2.7. See [example](http://demo.robustperception.io:9090/graph?g0.range_input=1h&g0.expr=delta(rate(node_context_switches_total%5B1m%5D)%5B1m%3A%5D)&g0.tab=0). Without subqueries, you'll have to use recording rules which is not an issue but requires time to build the history.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211027/discussion-between-michael-doubez-and-edhgoose).